# Verb negative-form + なる

Tags: grammar, verbs, conjugations

寝る → 寝るようになる

1. 寝ないようになる
2. 寝なくようになる
3. 寝なくなる

Hi guys, sorry if this has been asked before. I've learned in class that `寝なくなる` is the valid form, but are the first two forms valid as well?

Comment: Related: http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/16328/1478

Comment: Except that #2 is ungrammatical (spoiler), the question seems duplicate with the post above. Close or not?

Comment: @John I closed this question, because it seems to be answered by the linked question (together with broccoli forest's comment). If you want to understand why 寝なくようになる is ungrammatical, you can edit this question (or ask a new question). In case you edit the question, it will be automatically queued for reopening.