# Making adverb form of verb + なります

Tags: verbs, conjugations, adverbs

I was reading an [NHK article](https://www3.nhk.or.jp/news/easy/k10011929761000/k10011929761000.html) and came across this line:

お金{かね}を払{はら}うとき「キャッシュレス」を利用{りよう}する人{ひと}が増{ふ}えて、現金{げんきん}をあまり**使{つか}わなく**なっているためです。

It comes after a line that says "This is the first time the number of ATM's has decreased"

I translated this as "This is because the amount of people using cashless (methods) when paying with money is increasing, and so cash is becoming used less often"

Or something to that effect.

If my parsing is correct then 使う(non-past positive verb)→使わない(non-past negative verb)→使わなく(negative adverbial).

My question is what would be the analogous adverbial form if I wanted to say something like "Debit cards are becoming used more often" using a similar sentence structure but a positive sense of the verb?

Comment: Does this help: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/16328/difference-between-%e6%9b%b8%e3%81%8b%e3%81%aa%e3%81%84%e3%82%88%e3%81%86%e3%81%ab%e3%81%aa%e3%81%a3%e3%81%9f-and-%e6%9b%b8%e3%81%8b%e3%81%aa%e3%81%8f%e3%81%aa%e3%81%a3%e3%81%9f ?

Comment: Yes! So it seems that there is only this adverb conjugation for non-past negative ..