# What does "来なくなります" mean?

Tags: grammar, newspaper-grammar

In

> 人が話す声が熊に聞こえると、熊が近くに来なくなります。

What does "来なくなります" mean?

I assume it is くる + ない + なる, then こなくなる, then こなくなります. I have difficulty understand why is なる needed. I searched in dictionary and found 無くなる is a word by itself but it is not negation like ない。

Why not just 熊が近くに来ないです? Is there some kind of idiomatic phrase I'm missing?

Thanks!

Comment: Should be a dup [Difference between 書かないようになった and 書かなくなった?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/16328)

Comment: 来る is くる, not いる

Comment: @Leebo Thanks, I stand corrected.

Comment: @sundowner 自分の回答を書いてからそのリンクみたら、同じこと書いてましたね…

Answer (score 3):

The key verb here is なる, which basically means "to become". In its simplest use case, you can apply it to adjectives:

- 強くなる
  to become strong
- 強くなくなる
  to become not strong → to stop being strong / to become weaker

なる is more versatile than English "become"; you can apply it also to verbs and express a change of situation (ability, habit, etc.). However, you need ように between the two verbs.

- 学校に行くようになる
  to start to go to school
- 自転車に乗れるようになる
  to come to be able to ride a bicycle

You can construct a negative version of these:

- 学校に行かないようになる
  to start not to go to school → to stop going to school
- 自転車に乗れないようになる
  to come to be unable to ride a bicycle

Now, remember that Japanese ない conjugates like an adjective. This means you can directly attach ない and なる without ように, just like the first example above!

- 学校に行かなくなる
  to start not to go to school → to stop going to school
- 自転車に乗れなくなる
  to come to be unable to ride a bicycle

You can use this handy shortcut only when the main verb is negated, but it's usually preferred over ～ないようになる. Therefore, 熊が近くに来なくなります is the same as 熊が近くに来ないようになります, and means "bears will stop coming closer" or "(with this,) bears won't come nearby anymore". Notice the *change in state* is expressed by なります, which is the key difference from 熊が近くに来ません. (By the way, to simply negate a verb, say 来ません instead of 来ないです.)

For details and more examples, see this article (especially the chart): [apieceofsushi.com: JLPT N4 Grammar 文法 -you ni naru 〜ようになる ‘to come to point that’ ‘to start to’ ‘to become able to’](https://apieceofsushi.com/jlpt-n4-grammar-%E6%96%87%E6%B3%95-you-ni-naru-%E3%82%88%E3%81%86%E3%81%AB%E3%81%AA%E3%82%8B-%E6%84%8F%E5%91%B3-meaning-%E4%BE%8B%E6%96%87-example/)

Comment: Thanks, I now understand the "change of situation" part, but "coming closer" (近くに来る) already convey a sense of "change of situation", so I guess with なる added it means "bear won't *even start* coming close"? If it was "熊が近くに来ません", then does the meaning change or is it just less emphasized? Thanks!

Comment: @dz902 Here, "change in state" refers to the change from 来る to 来ない. In other words, "stop coming" or "no longer comes". That is, a wild bear would normally try to approach you, but taking whatever measure mentioned in the article will change the situation; the bear will stop coming to you.